# Cannot see files in laravel on shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem. My laravel doesn't see images on shared hosting.

I have public folder in ~/domains/DOMAIN/public_html/APP and rest of files in ~/domains/DOMAIN/FILES.

My files are uploading to ~/domains/DOMAIN/FILES/storage/app/public/uploads/avatars

but in app I can't see this.

Here's the upload code:

```
public function addAvatar(Request $request) { $this->validate($request, [ 'file' => 'required', ]);

    $user = $this->model->getUserById(Auth::user()->id);

    $file = $request->file('file')->store('/public/uploads/avatars');

    $filename = $request->file('file')->hashName();

    $extension = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if($extension == 'png' OR $extension == 'jpg' OR $extension == 'jpeg'){

        $file = UserData::avatar($request, $filename, $user->id);

        return view('user.settings', compact('user')); 
    }
    else
    {
        $file = unlink($request->file('file'));

        return view('user.settings.files', compact('user'))->with('message', 'nope');
    }
}
```

can you help me what to do?

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
->store('avatars') //and make it public
Storage::put('file.jpg', $contents, 'public');
```

In [Laravel File Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#file-uploads) Docu there are some examples how to handle the uploads and storing

if you want to recieve them:

```
$contents = Storage::get('file.jpg'); 
//or just the url: 
$url = Storage::url('file1.jpg');
```

Comment: how to display it then?

Comment: what is $contents variable?